# append two Arrays into an Object with certain conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have these Arrays:

```
var nodes = [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5];
var edges = [{source: v1, target: v2},{source: v2, target: v3},{source: v3, target: v5}];
```

And also I have an Object :

```
var graph = {};
```

I want to append *"nodes"* and *"edges"* into *"graph"* object.
So at the end it should be like this :

```
graph = { nodes: [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5], edges: [{source: v1, target: v2},{source: v2, target: v3},{source: v3, target: v5}] };
```

Note that array names(nodes and edges) are inside my "graph" object.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing any code to accomplish this yourself yet?

Comment: `graph = {nodes:nodes,edges:edges}`??

Comment: @JaydipJadhav Or just `graph = { nodes, edges }` ?

Comment: Post your code here for us to have a look ?

Comment: Take a look to this: https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize your object like this

```
var graph = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};
```

or set values like this

```
var graph = {};
graph.nodes = nodes;
graph.edges = edges;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var nodes = ['v1','v2','v3','v4','v5'];
      var edges = [{source: 'v1', target: 'v2'},{source: 'v2', target: 'v3'},      {source: 'v3', target: 'v5'}];
      var graphs={nodes:nodes,edges:edges};
//method 1
      console.log(JSON.stringify(graphs));
//method2
      console.log(JSON.stringify({nodes,edges}));
    });
```

Use any of the method shown above

Answer (score 1):

```
v1= "test1";
v2= "test2";
v3= "test3";
v4= "test4";
v5= "test5";
var nodes = [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5];
var edges = [{source: v1, target: v2},{source: v2, target: v3},{source: v3, target: v5}];



var graph ={};

graph.edges =edges;
graph.nodes =nodes;

console.log(graph);
```